# Ubuntu Unity crash due to glade2script-python3, can I remove it?

Tags: unity, 22.04, crash, glade

It happened twice in ~2 months, since I replaced Gnome with Unity (ubuntu 22.04.1).

While watching a YT video in Chrome, and Unity just froze. The video was looping (audio only), repeating the last 2 seconds forever. Mouse and keyboard dead. <kbd>Crl-Alt-Fx</kbd> not working. `ssh` to the desktop unresponsive. Had to reset the computer.

Both times, `/var/crash` showed that the culprit seems to be `glade2script-python3`.

The man says that

> Glade2script allows a script (Bash, Python or other) to display and interact with a GUI (created with Glade).

Can I safely remove glade2script-python3? Is it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if your package is used by another one (reverse dependency), use

```
apt-cache rdepends glade2script-python3
```

This will show you the list where your culprit is used.  After that, you will have to decide whether you remove it and the said packages or not.
Alternatively, you can simulate a removal and carefully identify what the consequences would be on your system:

```
sudo apt-get -s remove glade2script-python3
```

Comment: Good guess! According to the dependencies, `gladescript*` and `boot-sav` came seemingly from the install of `boot-repair`, which is actually (almost) useless in an installed Ubuntu (since boot-repair has to be started from a USB stick Ubuntu). Now why gladescript was *actively* running while boot-repair was not started since the last boot, that's another interesting question... Anyway, that's all purged now.